# Openning in a new tab an HTML file returned from the server instead of dowloading it

Tags: javascript

Im using the following JS code to fetch an HTML file embedded in the server response:

`$window.open('some url...');`

The file is returned in the response body and being downloaded to the computer's file system.

I wish to open the file in a new tab in the browser (Chrome) rather than dowloading it.

Thanks

Comment: That depends on your HTTP response headers.

Comment: What should be the header?

Currently it is as follows:
response.setContentType("text/html");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +fileName);

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try it by calling function like this :-

```
function myFunction() {
window.open("..some url");
}
```

if it still download there is must be some other problem with your code

Comment: I've neglected to mention that this is exactly what I'm doing. The $window.open is invoked by calling a function as you described and still the file is being downloaded.

Comment: i think there is some problem in you url please check it first

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Disposition` tells the browser to treat a file as a download.

Remove that header.